# BundleConfig.cs not generating script references

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, bundle, asp.net-mvc-5

I've been trying to get MVC 5 remote validation working in my little project. I've been reading enough about bundling in order to get the basics of it. I created a bundle for my `jqueryval` bundle, like so:

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")
            .Include("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js")
            );
```

However, when I publish the page, view source, the only scripts that are rendered, are as follows:

```
    <script src="/myApp/Scripts/jquery-2.1.0.js"></script>
    <script src="/myApp/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
```

notice that the `query.validate.unobstrusive.js` is missing. Now I know this is the key component in getting my validation working, because when I manually add the `query.validate.unobstrusive.js` to my view page like so:

```
  @section Scripts {
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
  @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
  <script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript" />
  }
```

everything just works.

So now I'm left wondering, is there something I'm doing wrong with the Bundling? Why would this script not show up?

Comment: You're missing the `.min` as seen in your second source that works. (I'm guessing you just had a bad path in the bundle)

Comment: Actually, I just had `.min` in my hardcoded version because I was working in a development environment. MVC handles selecting the correct file for you. So, my solution has both the `.js` and the `.min.js` files for `jquery.validate.unobstrusive`. Depending on the config you publish with, MVC selects the correct one. So all you need it to `.Include("~/Scripts/myFile.js")` and it will choose the appropriate file as long as both the `.js` and `.js.min` exist in the directory you specify, which mine do.

Comment: @tymeJV, while it wasn't the `min` that was missing, you made me have a closer look at my code. Turns out I spelled "unobtrusive" incorrectly! DOH! I corrected the spelling and the bundle works. 2nd set of eyes always helps.

Comment: Got to love non-obvious typo's :). Also, thanks for the info on Bundles and the `.min` files, didn't know that. Just started using the Bundles about 2 weeks ago.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have it enabled in your web.config?

```
<appSettings>
   <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
   <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
</appSettings>
```

You won't need to include it in the BundleConfig.cs.  Just make sure you have`jquery.validate.unobstrusive.js`and`jquery.validate.unobstrusive.min.js`in your`scripts`folder